# Slow mysql query when additional select criteria added

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some issues with an sql query that is going extremely slowly in an INNODB MySql table.  There's only 32,000 rows and all the conditions in the where clause are indexed and either bits or bigints.  I wouldn't have expected a speed issue at all but sometimes the queries take 2 mins to complete.  It's difficult to tell because of caching but it appears that if I remove all of the select criteria from the query except for the id then the query executes in milliseconds.

The rows are large as they store email html so often a row is 1MB.  When the query runs the computer uses a lot of harddrive resource which appears to be the source of the speed slowdown.  As far as I know though the database shouldn't need to use any additional resource when select criteria are added, first it finds the rows and then it pulls out the information it needs just for those rows.  Can someone correct me if I'm wrong or let me know if some other setting could explain this behaviour.

As requested here is the query:

select aplosemail0_.id as id4353_, aplosemail0_.active as active4353_, aplosemail0_.deletable as deletable4353_, aplosemail0_.editable as editable4353_, aplosemail0_.persistentData as persiste5_4353_, aplosemail0_.dateCreated as dateCrea6_4353_, aplosemail0_.dateInactivated as dateInac7_4353_, aplosemail0_.dateLastModified as dateLast8_4353_, aplosemail0_.displayId as displayId4353_, aplosemail0_.owner_id as owner37_4353_, aplosemail0_.userIdCreated as userIdC10_4353_, aplosemail0_.userIdInactivated as userIdI11_4353_, aplosemail0_.userIdLastModified as userIdL12_4353_, aplosemail0_.parentWebsite_id as parentW38_4353_, aplosemail0_.automaticSendDate as automat13_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailFrame_id as emailFrame39_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailGenerationType as emailGe14_4353_, aplosemail0_.email_generator_type as email15_4353_, aplosemail0_.email_generator_id as email16_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailReadDate as emailRe17_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailSentCount as emailSe18_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailSentDate as emailSe19_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailStatus as emailSt20_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailTemplate_id as emailTe40_4353_, aplosemail0_.emailType as emailType4353_, aplosemail0_.encryptionSalt as encrypt22_4353_, aplosemail0_.forwardedEmail_id as forward41_4353_, aplosemail0_.fromAddress as fromAdd23_4353_, aplosemail0_.hardDeleteDate as hardDel24_4353_, aplosemail0_.htmlBody as htmlBody4353_, aplosemail0_.incomingReadRetryCount as incomin26_4353_, aplosemail0_.isAskingForReceipt as isAskin27_4353_, aplosemail0_.isIncomingEmailDeleted as isIncom28_4353_, aplosemail0_.isSendingPlainText as isSendi29_4353_, aplosemail0_.isUsingEmailSourceAsOwner as isUsing30_4353_, aplosemail0_.mailServerSettings_id as mailSer42_4353_, aplosemail0_.maxSendQuantity as maxSend31_4353_, aplosemail0_.originalEmail_id as origina43_4353_, aplosemail0_.outerEmailFrame_id as outerEm44_4353_, aplosemail0_.plainTextBody as plainTe32_4353_, aplosemail0_.removeDuplicateToAddresses as removeD33_4353_, aplosemail0_.repliedEmail_id as replied45_4353_, aplosemail0_.sendStartIdx as sendSta34_4353_, aplosemail0_.subject as subject4353_, aplosemail0_.uid as uid4353_ from AplosEmail aplosemail0_ where aplosemail0_.emailType=0 and aplosemail0_.emailStatus<>2 and aplosemail0_.mailServerSettings_id=7 and aplosemail0_.active=1 order by aplosemail0_.id DESC limit 50

Comment: Have you tred `explain` to check why your query is so slow? Probably performing full table scan

Comment: Check the execution plan and make sure there is not table or index scan. For better performance it should be index seek. If requires you can create cover index.

Comment: It's running super fast today, it maybe because I increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size to double the size and the harddrive is no longer required.

Comment: Here's the output from 'Explain extended' id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,aplosemail0_,ref,FK6FA5937BFD08B0CE,FK6FA5937BFD08B0CE,9,const,1,100.00,"Using where"